# How can I reshape from long to wide a dataset imported from Eurostat package?

Tags: r, tidyr, reshape

I have the following dataset, from the Eurostat package:

```r
IPI <- get_eurostat("sts_inpr_m") %>% 
  select("geo", "time", "values") %>%
  mutate(time=format(as.Date(time, "%Y-%m-%d"))) %>%
  filter(geo %in% c("ES", "IT", "FR", "EU28", "EA19"))
```

```
structure(list(geo = c("EA19", "ES", "FR", "IT", "EA19", "ES"
), time = c("2022-12-01", "2022-12-01", "2022-12-01", "2022-12-01", 
"2022-12-01", "2022-12-01"), values = c(68.3, 110.6, 71, 59.1, 
-1.9, 16.5)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

And I want it to be wide. So far I have tried:

```r
IPI_wide <- pivot_wider(IPI, names_from = "geo", values_from="values")
```

And I get this, which doesn't make sense...:

[image]

Comment: Well, your Eurostat data has 4 more variables "indic_bt", "nace_r2", "s_adj" and "unit" which you simply drop. For this reason you have multiple values per time and country and when you reshape to wide you end up with a list column. To fix that remove the select statement or filter your data according to your needs before dropping columns to get rid of the multiple values.

Comment: It would help to have sample data to better inform the answer. Can you please [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(head(IPI))` (or a just-large-enough sample to get the point across)?

Comment: I added some sample data.

Comment: At the end, I did what @stefan told me and it works.

Answer (score 0):

> At the end, I did what @stefan told me and it works - OP

What Stefan said:

> Well, your Eurostat data has 4 more variables "indic_bt", "nace_r2", "s_adj" and "unit" which you simply drop. For this reason you have multiple values per time and country and when you reshape to wide you end up with a list column. To fix that remove the select statement or filter your data according to your needs before dropping columns to get rid of the multiple values.